# Ionic 2: Tabs remain in all views

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to use the Ionic 2 tab layout, but only on certain pages.  Is it possible to remove the tab layout after navigating away from a page with the tab layout?

Answer (score 1):

There are already tons of questions about hiding tab bar. Please do some more research next time. But to save your time, here you go:

In your app.module.ts file

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      tabsHideOnSubPages: true,
    })
  ]
  ...
})
```